# Prove that the integral converges (to use the theorem about the mean).

Tags: integration

***Task:***

$\phi \left(b\right)=\int _1^be^{cosx}\cdot ln\left(x\right)dx\:$

Prove that: $\lim _n\left(\frac{\phi \left(b\right)}{b^2}\right)=0$

***My solution:***

The theorem about the mean choose: $a=1, b=b,f(x)=\phi \left(b\right),g(x)=\frac{1}{b^2}$, then $g(x)>0$ on $[1,b]$;

Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ continuous and integrated over the interval of integration. Therefore, we have the estimate:

$-1\int _1^b\:\frac{1}{b^2}dx\le \int _1^b\:\frac{e^x-ln\left(x\right)}{b^2}dx\le \int _1^b\:\frac{1}{b^2}dx$

My teacher put a "minus". That is, I had no right. I would like you to know what's wrong with my decision.

Comment: Even if you will get a good answer here, I suggest you to ask your teacher. He or she will probably have the very best reason. In what you write above, I wonder what $n$ is in the limit (or rather, what is the limit you want to calculate?), and if you mean $e^{\cos x}$ or $e^x$?

Comment: But still. If I then ask for help, then there is no opportunity to ask the teacher.

Comment: In the estimation the integrand is different to the thing you shall prove, is that on purpose ?

Comment: For $b$ greater than $1$ the integral is positive and less than $(b-1)e^1\ln b$. I see nothing like that in the post.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your solution at all. How on earth do you come up with those inequalities? What do you mean by "theorem about the mean"? It looks like you bound $-1\leq e^x-\ln x\leq 1$, but why is that? Your solution is, in fact, very unclear to me. Correcting it, I would have put a big question mark on it.

Comment: Also, your title says "prove that the integral converges", and the assignment seems to be something completely different...